# python ipyvuetify equivalent to ipywidgets Output

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, voila, ipyvuetify

A simple Output ipywidget to display text might look like this:

```
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
out
```

this element is very useful when rendering with voila.

What is the equivalent in ipyvuetify?

I did not find an equivalent in the ipyvuetify documentation:
https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#create-an-ipyvuetify-widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the divider component of vuetify:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dividers/

in ipyvuetify this can be accessed with v.Divider().

it works on its own:

```
v.Divider()
```

or as child element in other elements:

```
v.Html(tag='div', children=['first text', v.Divider(), 'second text'])
```